# AuthzForce Core PDP engine configuring PIP

Tags: java

I've downloaded AuthzForce Core PDP engine and would like to add some PIP providers but cannot find any documentation on how to do it.

Can you help me with that or give some advices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are requesting help in searching for docs?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AuthzForce Core's github. There is a wiki page called "Attribute Providers"

Comment: I would be grateful if you [accept or vote up the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [wiki site](https://github.com/authzforce/core/wiki) of authzforce. There's a list of pages there and you can find the information you need in the one that says "[Attribute Providers](https://github.com/authzforce/core/wiki/Attribute-Providers)"